# Android web browser reloads source files in HTML5 audio elements - how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

I have an HTML5 audio element that is set up as follows:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" id="audio1">
    <source src="click.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="click.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

I'm firing the `play()` event with javascript. The problem is that everytime I call `play()` the source is re-downloaded in the Android browser. I can see this happening via the network indicator and I've confirmed by enabling flight mode; sounds no longer play when no internet connection is available even if they've been played previously. This also happens with Dolphin, but does not happen with Firefox Mobile or Opera Mobile. How can I set the audio element up to prevent this from happening in the offending browsers?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the cache for web view

```
settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setCacheMode(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1048576000); // 100 MB
```

Comment: I believe your code is for native apps. My code is for a webpage.

Comment: oh. i don't think that is possible using HTML / javascript. I guess u can post this bug to android developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on `updatetime` to `pause()` the playback a second before reaching the end of the audio and rewind before playing it again. Android will not flush the audio then.

Comment: This looks promising. I will give it a try.